# Is there any relation between Berkovich spaces over $\Bbb Z$ and Arakelov theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, berkovich-geometry, arakelov-theory

As I understand it, both Arakelov geometry and Berkovich geometry over $\Bbb Z$ (or $\mathcal O_K$) consider geometric objects that contain in some sense information about both archimdean and nonarchimedean places. So it seems natural (at least to my naïve mind) to ask if there is any relation between the two approaches.

Comment: Have you checked out Sections 3 and 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.13587.pdf. The authors define a theory of adelic line bundles and integration pairings using Berkovich spaces over $\mathbb{Z}$ and relate this to classical Arakelov intersection pairings.

Comment: @JacksonMorrow thanks for the reference!